# What is the meaning of this ending line?

Tags: plot-explanation, midway-2019

In Midway (2019) movie ends with this line:

> The sea remembers its own.

What is the meaning of this ending line?

Comment: This is about the meaning of a phrase, not about it's use in this movie? Wrong SE for that.

Comment: @CGCampbell (Before jumping to conclusions) or is it about the meaning of the sentence within the film?